# Logo getting cut off on facebook like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I am having a problem where my logo is getting cut off at the bottom on my facebook like button. You can see what i mean here on my home page http://www.organicgrowshop.co.uk

I have tried changing the height in the code and this does change the height of the iframe but not the actual image that is generated??

this is the code im using :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FThe-Organic-Grow-Shop%2F229793147037672&amp;width=180&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=120" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:180px; height:120px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

please help! Im a total noob at all this.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, pleasse ignore this post, ive solved the problem now!

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting. Log into the facebook account the button is linked to, click the "change profile picture" link that pops up if you hover over your current image. Once there, click "edit miniature image" (or something like, that, facebook is in dutch for me). Select the "scale to fit" checkbox. That should fix it. If not, Upload your logo again, but make sure it's a square image, and once again make sure "scale to fit" is checked.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing similar issue, my solution was to set the data-href link to the URL of the Facebook account rather than to the url of the web site itself.